# How do you factor the cubic polynomial $-x^3+x^2+12$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, cubics

How would I factor the cubic polynomial $-x^3+x^2+12$? Grouping doesn't work. The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) says $\pm1,\pm2, \pm4, \pm6, \pm12$ are the possible rational roots $r$ for the linear term, but trying synthetic division $(x-r)$ doesn't divide the polynomial for any of these.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot factor this to find the roots. One way to solve the cubic is to first convert it into a depressed cubic (without the $x^2$ term). To do this, we have to make the substitution $x=y-\dfrac{b}{3a}$.
$$-x^3+x^2+12=0$$
$$-(x^3-x^2-12)=0$$
$$=-\left[\left(y-\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^3\right) - \left(y-\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^2\right) + 12\right]=0$$
Expanding the expression and simplifying gives us:
$$-\left(y^3 + \dfrac{1}{3}y + \dfrac{326}{27}\right)=0$$
$$y^3+\dfrac{1}{3}y + \dfrac{326}{27}=0$$
$$y^3+\dfrac{1}{3}y = -\dfrac{326}{27}$$
The depressed cubic is now in the form $y^3 + Ay = B$. To solve this we have to assume two variables, $s$ and $t$, with the condition that:
$$3st = A$$
$$s^3 - t^3 = B$$
$y = s-t$ will be a root of the cubic. This is proved by substituting $(s-t)$ into $y$, $3st$ into $A$, and $s^3-t^3$ into $B$. You can do this on your own time; I will not write the proof here because I am lazy.
Let's derive a formula to convert our cubic into a quadratic. We first solve $3st = B$ for $s$, and substitute it into $s^3-t^3=B$
$$s = \dfrac{A}{3t}$$
$$\left(\dfrac{A}{3t}\right)^3 - t^3 = B$$
$$\dfrac{A^3}{27t^3} - B - t^3 = 0$$
Multiply by $-t^3$ on both sides.
$$-\dfrac{A^3}{27} + Bt^3 + t^3\cdot t^3 = 0$$
$$t^6 + Bt^3 - \dfrac{A^3}{27}$$
Finally, we make the substitution $u=t^3$ to obtain:
$$u^2 + Bu - \dfrac{A^3}{27} = 0$$
Using our formula, we get:
$$u^2 - \dfrac{326}{27}u - \dfrac{\frac{1}{9}}{27} = 0$$
Multiply by 27 on both sides.
$$27u^2 - 326u - \dfrac{1}{9} = 0$$
Multiply by 9 on both sides.
$$243u^2 - 2934u - 1 = 0$$
I can tell that the solution is **not** going to be pretty. Let's find the solution.
$$u = \dfrac{2934 \pm \sqrt{2934^2 - 4(243)(-1)}}{2\times 243}$$
$$u = \dfrac{2934 \pm \sqrt{8609328}}{486}$$
$$u = \dfrac{2934 \pm 4\sqrt{556833}}{486}$$
$$u = \dfrac{1467 \pm 2\sqrt{556833}}{243}$$
Remember $u=t^3$. Also discard the negative square root.
$$t^3 = \dfrac{1467 + 2\sqrt{556833}}{243}$$
$$t = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1467 + 2\sqrt{556833}}{243}}$$
Substitute the value of t^3 into the equation $s^3 + t^3 = B$ to obtain $s$.
$$s^3 + t^3 = -\dfrac{326}{27}$$
$$s^3 = -\dfrac{326}{27} - t^3$$
$$s^3 = -\dfrac{326}{27} - \dfrac{1467 + 2\sqrt{556833}}{243}$$
$$s = \sqrt[3]{-\dfrac{326}{27} - \dfrac{1467 + 2\sqrt{556833}}{243}}$$
$$s = \sqrt[3]{-\dfrac{326 + 1467 + 2\sqrt{56833}}{243}}$$
$$s = \sqrt[3]{-\dfrac{1793 + 2\sqrt{56833}}{243}}$$
Remember $y = s-t$:
$$y = s-t$$
$$y= \sqrt[3]{-\dfrac{1793 + 2\sqrt{56833}}{243}} - \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1467 + 2\sqrt{556833}}{243}}$$
Finally, remember $x = y - \dfrac{b}{3a}$:
$$x = y - \dfrac{b}{3a}$$
$$x = \sqrt[3]{-\dfrac{1793 + 2\sqrt{556833}}{243}} - \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1467 + 2\sqrt{556833}}{243}} - \dfrac{1}{3}$$
The solution to the cubic equation $-x^3 + x^2 + 12$ is (hopefully):
$$\boxed{x = \sqrt[3]{-\dfrac{1793 + 2\sqrt{556833}}{243}} - \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1467 + 2\sqrt{556833}}{243}} - \dfrac{1}{3}}$$
By the way, the mathematician Scipione del Ferro was the first person to invent a "cubic formula" using the method described above. In case you were wondering, the cubic formula is what it sounds like: a formula that can be used to solve cubic equations.
The roots of any cubic equation $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$ is:
$$x = \sqrt[3]{\left(\dfrac{-b^3}{27a^3} + \dfrac{bc}{6a^2} - \dfrac{d}{2a}\right) + \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{-b^3}{27a^3} + \dfrac{bc}{6a^2}-\dfrac{d}{2a}\right)^2 - \left(\dfrac{c}{3a}-\dfrac{b^2}{9a^2}\right)^3}} + \sqrt[3]{\left(\dfrac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\dfrac{bc}{6a^2}-\dfrac{d}{2a}\right) + \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\dfrac{bc}{6a^2}-\dfrac{d}{2a}\right)^2 - \left(\dfrac{c}{3a}-\dfrac{b^2}{9a^2}\right)^3}} - \dfrac{b}{3a}$$
I really, really do not think that you should memorize this formula because even if you do, it will be very, very inefficient.